# Get PublicKeyToken from certificate or pfx file

Tags: .net, powershell, x509certificate

I generate a certificate and pvk file and then create a pfx file:

```
makecert.exe -sv My.pvk ^
             -n CN="My name" ^
             -e 12/31/2100 -r ^
             My.cer

pvk2pfx.exe -pvk My.pvk ^
            -spc My.cer ^
            -pfx My.pfx
```

Later I use `Get-PfxCertificate` in PowerShell along with the `GetRSAPublicKey` extension method to read the public key:

```
$pfxCertificate = Get-PfxCertificate -FilePath $pfxPath
$rsaPublicKey = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.RSACertificateExtensions]::GetRSAPublicKey($pfxCertificate)
```

Now I am stuck in obtaining the PublicKeyToken and appreciate any help on that.

Comment: Note that `makecert.exe` tool is deprecated: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SecCrypto/makecert.

Comment: Oh, I was not aware of that. Thanks for pointing it out!